# How to execute pivot longer in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

Below is the sample data and my first attempt at doing this. The desired result is at the bottom. No errors but not yielding the desired result. My primary question is this... to get the desired result, what should i put in the "cols" section?

```
 periodyear3 <-c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
 month3<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
 indcode3<-c(624410,624410,624410,624410,624410,624410,72,72,72,72,72,72)
 employment3 <-c(25,25,26,27,28,29,85,86,87,88,89,90)
 wages3 <-c(10000,10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,12510,12515,12520,12520,16528,19874)

 pivotexample <- data.frame(periodyear3,month3,indcode3,employment3,wages3)

 indcomp <- pivotexample %>%
    dplyr::select("indcode3","periodyear3","month3","employment3") %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = periodyear3:employment3, names_to = "indcode", values_to ="employment")


periodyear3    month3    624410      72
    2020          1         25       85
    2020          2         25       86
    2020          3         26       87
    2020          4         27       88
    2020          5         28       89
    2020          6         29       90
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to make it `_wider`, not `_longer`. Perhaps this:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(pivotexample, c(periodyear3, month3), 
                   names_from="indcode3", values_from="employment3")
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   periodyear3 month3 `624410`  `72`
#         <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1        2020      1       25    85
# 2        2020      2       25    86
# 3        2020      3       26    87
# 4        2020      4       27    88
# 5        2020      5       28    89
# 6        2020      6       29    90
```